# I want to merge array's and use a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have a number of array's and I want to combine them.

I have:

```
[amount] => 1 
[amount] => 1

[titel] => item
[titel] => item


[price] => 5
[price] => 5
```

the amount of values can be more or less.

and i want something like this:

```
[0] => 
    [amount] => 1 
    [titel] => item
    [price] => 5
[1] => 
    [amount] => 1 
    [titel] => item
    [price] => 5
```

Is it possible to create a php `foreach` so I can use the `amount`, `title` and `price` values ?

Comment: What's wrong with mentioned `array_merge()` ?

Comment: Have you [looked for a solution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) yet?

Comment: I had typed it wrong so it's corrected now

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array containing both arrays like this:

```
$newArray = array($array1, $array2);
```

Then you can browse it by doing:

```
foreach ($newArray as $item)
{
    echo $item['iteml'] . ': ' . $item['amount'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new array, and append your arrays to it.

```
  $newArray[] = $yourArray;
```

Then you can use a foreach loop to traverse the

```
  $newArray
```